# Linux way to get Summation of elements on right

Tags: shell, awk, command

I have the following text stored in a .txt file - I want to have the sum of 'NUM_OF_USERS' using linux command.

[image]

so the desired result here is - `Total 236`

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/18887).

Comment: roger that captain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this can help:

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$2} END {print "Total "sum}' input_file.txt
```

Comment: You can make it even shorter by omit the `BEGIN` part. `awk` initialize the variable on first access automaticly.

Comment: @finswimmer, true, but with `BEGIN` it make code more readable. And who knows, maybe in next version will be no variables initialization :)

Answer (score 0):

Done by python worked fine

```
#!/usr/bin/python
sum=0
m=open('filename','r')
m.readline()
k=[]
for i in m:
    k.append(i.strip().split('\t')[-1].strip())
for j in k:
    y=int(j)
    sum=sum+y
print "Total is {0}".format(sum)
```

output

```
 python script.py 
Total is 236
```